# setHint fails during Runnable

Tags: android, android-edittext, runnable

My code is intended to update the hint of an `EditText` with the time, allowing the user to enter a different time as the text or use the hint if the user has not entered anything like so:

```
mTicker = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            time.setHint(new TimeDate().getTime());

            long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
            spaceTimeHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
        }
```

This code runs except that the `EditText` remains blank; if you exchange `setHint` with `setText` then everything works fine. Is this a bug?

I realize I should probably use the `DateTimePicker` or whatever but I haven't gotten around to that yet, and this issue would occur regardless of what string I try to `setHint` with.

Answer (score 0):

```
mTicker = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
            time.setHint(new TimeDate().getTime());

            long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
            spaceTimeHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
          }
         });

        }
}
```

Enclose it in a runOnUiThread, let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hrm, I didn't think you were supposed to do things on the UI thread unless you had to. At any rate, the `EditText` remained blank